# Best way to add a DNS wildcard record for a domain

Tags: domain-name-system, cname-record, wildcard-subdomain

What is the best way to add a DNS wildcard record for a domain?

I want `example.net`, `www.example.net`, `a.b.c.www.example.net`, ... going to one server.

Now I use:

```
example.net.    60  IN  A       1.2.3.4
*.example.net.  60  IN  CNAME   example.net.
```

Is it possible to do it simpler?

Comment: What is wrong with what you're currently doing ?

Comment: What benefit would you get by being "simpler"? (e.g. less records, less lookups, easier for an end-user) I can't tell what your measure of success is, and that looks pretty good.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Either this, or a direct A record (saves one lookup) are the best options you have, yes.

```
*.example.net.  60  IN  A 1.2.3.4
```

Comment: You still need example.net. in there

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use something like DNSmasq and setup:
address=/.domain.tld/192.168.0.1
http://davejamesmiller.com/blog/linux-installing-dnsmasq-wildcard-local-domains has a guide on setting up DNSmasq (I know from experience DNSMasq is available for Linux and Macs).

Which OS are you running on and what DNS server are you running?

Comment: Why would he want to get into the DNS service business for a domain with one server? What user or admin problem does it solve? Is is worth the effort? No down vote, but without further explanation, this seems like a solution in search of a problem.

Comment: It's how I've wildcarded all my development domains. Use DNSmasq and anything *.mydevelopment.tld will go to my development machine. He's obviously running some sort of DNS service (either on his machine for himself, on a server for others or on a third party DNS service): I've given one solution for two out of three possibilities.